# XPath - select nodes without certain internal nodes

Tags: xpath

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node4>
      <node3>
      </node3>
    </node4>
  </node2>
  <node2>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

How do I select all `node2` which doesn't have internal `node3`? The result should be the second `node2`.

PS: `node3` could be in any level, but must be in `node2`

Answer (score 1):

x-path:

`//node2[not(.//node3)]`

will select all `node2`s in the whole document with no descendant `node3`.